# Deploying to Heroku: How to change filepath for build script in package.json file for NextJS project

Tags: javascript, heroku, next.js

I currently have my project structured as

Root:

```
Folder 1/
Folder 2/
Folder 3/
..
Frontend/
```

And in my front end folder is my Nextjs project; package.json file and all. Heroku wants the content in Frontend/ in the root directory and I am trying to avoid this to not break my project. So I copied package.json over to the root directory.

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,  
  "engines": {
    "node": "17.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.6",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "next": "^12.2.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "solc": "^0.8.15",
    "web3": "^1.7.4",
    "web3-utils": "^1.7.4"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to set the file path to Frontend so that when heroku initiates build script, it knows to look into the frontend folder and not the root directory?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what I needed to do, in my package.json file, heroku runs the build script first so I changed it from

`"build": "next build",`

to

`"build": "cd frontend ; next build",`

Solved that issue.